# Static file in Django wkhtmltopdf

Tags: django, macos, wkhtmltopdf

I have a problem with generating a PDF file - django does not provide for wkhtmltopdf static files if the path looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'flot/fms.css' %}">
```

but if I give a direct path it works:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8000/static/flot/fms.css">
```

The problem with static files is only when generating PDF from web, from console files generate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly configure `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` for production. Depending on `STATICFILES_DIRS` and what `STATICFILES_FINDERS` you have configured, your static sources will be located together with your application's sources, while the `STATIC_ROOT` must be outside the path of your sources since this data is transient by nature.

This means that you must rely on running `$ python manage.py collectstatic` in production. Paths matching `STATIC_URL` should be handled by your web server, with the root configured to match `STATIC_ROOT` from where the files will be served.

You can review the [`django.contrib.staticfiles`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) app guide and the guide on [deploying static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/static-files/deployment/) in production from the documentation for more nitty-gritty details.

Comment: What about while in development phase?

Comment: for production use absolute path like given in the question or run collect_static every time you change a static file.

Comment: in addition to setting the STATIC_ROOT properly, I needed to add the option "--enable-local-file-access" for the wkhtmktopdf script